# IIS does not load custom HTTP module from web.config

Tags: iis, asp.net, httpmodule

I have a custom HTTP module for an ASP.NET MVC3 website that I'm loading from web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="MyModule" type="MySolution.Web.MyHttpModule, MySolution.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

The module is loaded correctly when I run the site from within the VS web server (the break point in my Init method is hit) but when I host it in IIS it seems to be ignored (the breakpoint is missed and the module's functionality is absent from the site).  I have tried it on two separate IIS boxes with a similar result.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a setting I have to flick in enable IIS to load modules from a site's web.config?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured this out shortly after I asked the question - IIS7 uses a different schema for the web.config.  The correct place to load a module is now:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="MyModule" type="MySolution.Web.MyHttpModule, MySolution.Web" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: 've run into this same issue and this post help me fix it. I did find that it is required to keep both system.web/httpModules and system.webServer/modules to have my custom module work on both the local dev server and the production server.

Comment: WOW! thank you. I was really banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: Probably the difference is not IIS6 vs IIS7 but classic vs integrated mode.

Answer (score 4):

7 years later: It is not specific to the IIS version, it is specific to the application pool mode: classic versus integrated.

```
  <system.webServer><!--for integrated mode-->
    <modules>
      <add name="modulename" type="blabla.modulenamehere" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web><!--for classic mode-->
     <httpModules>
      <add name="modulename" type="blabla.modulenamehere" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. My Solution involved removing the Module first and then re-adding it to the system.webServer namespace.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
     <remove name="MyModule"/>
     <add name="MyModule" type="MySolution.Web.MyHttpModule, MySolution.Web" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This may be because we deploy to two different IIS servers. one on server 2003 (iis 6) and one on server 2008 (iis7+). So adding the module to  seemed to block it from loading in the  namespace. I could be wrong here...